# Unable to setup vcpkg CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE with KDevelop

Tags: c++, cmake, kdevelop

I have installed vcpkg according to the instructions provided [<strike>here</strike>](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/integration.md). I installed the libraries I wanted (in this case fmt and boost), then created a simple new project in KDevelop which runs just fine. Then to add my libraries to the project I added `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/VCPKG_LOCATION/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake` in the "Configure CMake settings", where there is an "Extra arguments field", of KDevelop (Right click on Project folder and then "Open Configuration...").
Then I simply added the following to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(fmt REQUIRED)
```

and I get the following error:

> By not providing "Findfmt.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
> has   asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
> "fmt", but   CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "fmt" with
> any of   the following names:
>
> ```
> fmtConfig.cmake
> fmt-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "fmt" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
> "fmt_DIR"   to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
> "fmt" provides a   separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
> been installed.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

It seems that KDevelop is not recognizing the toolchain file (even though I can clearly see in the build log that that CMake is being called with the "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE" as required). I have tried to setup the project similarly in Qt Creator which does seem to work perfectly fine.

Comment: I've cloned this repo (on a macOS system):
https://github.com/ariveron/boilerplate-pmm-vcpkg-cmake/tree/master
...and bumped into the very same problem.

Comment: I've now found that if I exchanging `fmt` with `SQLite3` it all works fine. I don't know if this is helpful to anyone, but maybe it is.

Answer (score -4):

You can install fmt package. With gcc/g++ installed,

```sh
git clone https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git
cd fmt
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```